# Save a params navigation which is in a flatlist, and display it in another screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-native-flatlist

I want to save a params navigation which is in a flatlist to display it on another screen.
This params is just a title which is stocked in an array for the flatlist.

### react-native

**ScreenA**

```
<FlatList data={ this.state.FlatListItems } keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor} ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
  renderItem={({item})=>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> { this.props.navigation.navigate('GraineChoisie', {titre1:
    this.props.FlatListItems.titre} )}} >
    <ChoixGrainesItem data={item} navigation={this.props.navigation} />
  </TouchableOpacity> } />
```

**FlatlistData**

```
export default aromatesData = [
  {
    titre: "Choix1",
    Description: " blablablablabala",
    Date: " le 00/00/00"
  }, {
    titre: "Choix2",
    Description: " blablablablabala",
    Date: " le 00/00/00"
  }
]
```

**ScreenB**

```
render() {
  let titre2 = this.props.navigation.getParam('titre1');
  alert(titre2);
  return (
    <Container style={styles.view}>
      <View
        <Text style={styles.Txt}>
          Vous avez choisie: {titre2}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </Container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
renderItem={({item}) => <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('GraineChoisie', {titre1: this.props.FlatListItems.titre} )}} >
```

with

```
renderItem={({item}) => <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('GraineChoisie', {titre1: item.titre } )}} >
```

Comment: Thanks Kamal for your replay. it's still not working because it can't find a variable "titre"

Comment: Finally it working.
I had another variable "titre" in the screenB x) .
Thanks a lot !